# How can I make a flex component have bottom fixed to browser bottom but top position dynamic

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, semantic-ui

I have a 3rd party component which is using `display:flex`. It behaves correctly in terms of it's top position, but I want the bottom of the component fixed to the bottom of the browser window.

https://codesandbox.io/s/18ox21zqm4

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Menu fixed="top" inverted>
      <Container>
        <Menu.Item as="a" header>
          Navbar
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as="a">Home</Menu.Item>
      </Container>
    </Menu>

    <div style={{ position: "fixed", top: "100px" }}>
      <Header as="h1">Dynamic Height Content</Header>

      <TextArea placeholder="This container height may grow or shrink based on content." />
      <Segment style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        <Grid>
          This 3rd party component which uses display:flex should have top just
          below above component, bottom fixed to browser window bottom (scales
          with window resize).
        </Grid>
      </Segment>
    </div>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have tried putting the component in a div with it's top and bottom fixed, using a ref of this div to get the height and derive what the height of the flex component should be, but the height from the ref does not update with window resize, only on browser reload.

How can I go about achieving my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like this but this is usually not a good coding practice (don't have enough reputation yet to comment)

```
<Segment style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: "100vh" }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual HTML output is:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 100px; bottom: 0px;">
  ...
  <div class="ui segment" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="ui grid" style="height: 100%;">This 3rd party component which uses display:flex should have top just below above component, bottom fixed to browser window bottom (scales with window resize).</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since your `<div class="ui segment">` has no height, giving `<div class="ui grid">` a height of `100%` isn't doing anything, since it's just `100%` of the parent. You need to add your `height: 100%` to the `<div class="ui segment">` aka `<Segment />`, so that it can fill the space set by the hight of the wrapping div.

```
<div style={{ position: "fixed", top: "100px", bottom: "0px" }}>
  <Header as="h1">Dynamic Height Content</Header>

  <TextArea placeholder="This container height may grow or shrink based on content." />
  <Segment style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: "100%" }}>
    <Grid>
      This 3rd party component which uses display:flex should have top just
      below above component, bottom fixed to browser window bottom (scales
      with window resize).
    </Grid>
  </Segment>
</div>
```